# What science fiction trilogy has the dead coming back to life

Tags: story-identification, science

This has been driving me crazy. There is a science fiction trilogy where the dead start coming back to life. It wasn't zombie fiction though.

In this trilogy, humanity has expanded to the stars, but then somehow the dead start coming back to life but they are "possessed" by different "Souls", so they are not zombies. There is an alien race that (atleast in the first book) knows the answer to why this is happening, but wants humanity to find out on its own.

Does anyone know which trilogy I'm talking about?

Comment: Sounds similar to [Farmer's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Jos%C3%A9_Farmer) [Riverworld](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riverworld).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Possibly [Night's Dawn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Night%27s_Dawn_Trilogy) trilogy by Peter F Hamilton?

Comment: Agreed, this sounds like a good match.

Comment: Sounds like the right answer to me

Answer (score 7):

That description does indeed sound exactly like Nights Dawn Trilogy. The satanist Dexter(?) unwittingly opens a dimensional rift into what seems to be hell. Souls then begin to escape by possessing living humans and suppressing the original consciousness of the host body.

The first book covers the 'outbreak' of possessed that spreads from a planet called Lalonde(?) into several other worlds and man made and grown habitats.

There is an alien race more advanced than humans called the Kiint who claim to have found their own solution to the problem, but refuse to enlighten desperate humans due tot their belief that every species must find its own solution on its own.

Spectacular series, I remember it like I read it yesterday. Except for the spelling of the Names lol.